# What is the name of One Piece background music in episode 296 during the scene Zoro decides to use Usopp as a sword?

Tags: one-piece, music

What is the music playing as Zoro decides to use Usopp as a sword while they are in Enies Lobby to get Robin back? It's in episode 296 and the music starts at about 22 minutes and 48 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Zoro decides to use Usopp as sword in episode 289: if you are referring to [this](http://youtu.be/wlm11O6nPYU?t=3m15s) moment the music is called [**Luffy's Fierce Attack!**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLdFWj4R5zo).

[image]